# Scatterplot looks strange

Tags: r, scale, pca

my scatterplot that shows the relationship between my principal component and one of my questionnaire items looks strange.
The scatterplot between two of my principal components looks great (see second image).

The item is measured on a Likert scale from 1 to 5 (1 = strongly disagree, 5 = strongly agree). The histogram of this item also has many gaps between the bars, which is strange to me too.

Please let me know which specific output you still need to figure this out.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is it strange ? You are plotting a categorical variable in the first case so it can only take value 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the principal components are both metric and the Likert scale is ordinal, so the values can only be integers from 1-5. In this regard the Scatterplot does not look strange but it might be the wrong type of plot. If you anyway want to use a scatterplot you can use *jitter(var, 0.3)* on the ordinal variable when creating the plot. 0.3 is just a suggestion, it's best if you just try what works. As you didn't provide a reproducible example I wasn't able to try it out.

Comment: Thanks! Make sense.Which type of data do you need?                                           When adding jitter to the ordinal variable, how does the code look like?  plot(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$RC1, Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Q4_Age)

Comment: So in the simplest way you could do `plot(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$RC1, jitter(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Q4_Age, 0.3))` , assuming that the second variable is the one that is supposed to be jittered.

Comment: Just for future questions: The type of data people need to help you is a reproducible example. That means you can create and upload a smaller dataset that resembles yours and also add the code you tried so far to the question. That makes it easier for others to try out solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, makes sense. Is there a convenient function for reproducing a subset of the data? Bye

Comment: Well that depends on the data. Sometimes it is best to just create a new dataset with fantasy variables that are just similar to your varaibles. Especially if it is confidential data. If you just want to reduce your dataset you can use for example `data2 <- data[1:20,1:3]` to for exatract the first 20 cases and the first 3 variables. If my answer solved your issue I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer :)

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I created a subset of the data. Is this sufficient for you? dput(dataset_extracted)
structure(list(TRUST2_I_trust_my_PAD_.to_keep_the_car_centered_in_the_lane = c(NA, 
4L, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), TRUST3_I_feel_hesitant_about_activating_the_PAD_mode_from_time_to_time = c(NA, 
4, 2, NA, 5, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), TRUST4_I_engage_in_other_activities_while_driving_my_PAC = c(NA, 
4L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), TRUST5_I_always_know_when_my_car_is_in_PAD_mode = c(NA, 
4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 30:40, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi, are these the variables you included in the principal component analysis? Because I don't see the variables you used in the example above (first comment of yours) to create the scatter plot. So can you please specify what kind of help you still need with this? I thought the initial issue was solved with the jitter() option as it was just a matter of vizualization and not of the actual data being displayed the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

For reproducibility, it is best if you provide a piece of the database you are using to make these scatterplots. It would also be great if you include the axes titles inside the graph.

To be honest, I dont see anything wrong with the first figure. Variable y (the questionare item) is a discrete variable between 1 and 5. It make sense that one result from the PC1 is match with more than one of the values of the item questionare.